# Get name of tag in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with parse xml file to retrieve a names of tags. I have a following xml file:

```
<city version="1.2" last_updated="Thu, 28 Aug 2014 12:10:38 +0300">
  <city id="8750">
    <name>Лондон</name>
    <name_en>London</name_en>
    <region/>
    <country>Великобритания</country>
    <country_id>826</country_id>
  </city>
  <city id="110254">
    <name>Лондон</name>
    <name_en>London</name_en>
    <region/>
    <country>Канада</country>
    <country_id>124</country_id>
  </city>
    <city id="58690">
    <name>Лондон</name>
   <name_en>London</name_en>
   <region>Arkansas</region>
   <country>Соединенные Штаты Америки</country>
   <country_id>840</country_id>
  </city>
  <city id="65450">
    <name>Лондон</name>
    <name_en>London</name_en>
    <region>Kentucky</region>
    <country>Соединенные Штаты Америки</country>
    <country_id>840</country_id>
  </city>
  <city id="76284">
    <name>Лондон</name>
    <name_en>London</name_en>
    <region>Ohio</region>
    <country>Соединенные Штаты Америки</country>
    <country_id>840</country_id>
  </city>
  <city id="131">
    <name>Макеевка</name>
    <name_en>Makiivka</name_en>
    <region>Донецкая область</region>
    <country>Украина</country>
    <country_id>804</country_id>
  </city>
</city>
```

I want to do array or select list with all name of tag for example country. I have following code:

```
  string filePath = String.Format("http://xml.weather.co.ua/1.2/city/?search={0}", name);
            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(filePath);

            if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement != null)
                foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("city"))

                    yield return new SelectListItem
                    {

                        Text = xmlNode.Value,
                        Value = xmlNode.ToString()
                    };
        }
```

How to solve this problem? Any idea?

Comment: OK. What's not working in your code? Any exception? Which error? Where? Unexpected results? What? BTW IMO few extra { } will help readability a lot...

Comment: I want get all value with tag country and I do not know how

Comment: I look here cool guys who sit current minusovat may not have but to help

Comment: Your xml example is not good to read...

Comment: I mean: you wrote some code. Doesn't it work? Where it fails? If you have any exception then post it. Unexpected results? Describe them.

Comment: it is read better http://xml.weather.co.ua/1.2/city/?search=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD

Comment: well I can tell you what I want in the end there is a field in which the user enters the city, I appeal to this line http://xml.weather.co.ua/1.2/city/?search=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0% BD% D0% B4% D0% BE% D0% BD and then through this method I do autocomplete by jquery

Comment: I think it is better to create one tag with all values(country, country_id) and so on.

Comment: Sowiarz if you can please write code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my idea but you have to create list "names" before. Try this LINQ to xml:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("your xml file");
foreach (var elem in xDoc.Document.Descendants("country"))
{
    names.Add(elem.Name);
}
```

If you can modify an xml to for me more clear form like that:

```
<city id="8750" name="Лондон" name_en="London" region="" country="Великобритания" country_en="826"/>
```

What for create that number of tags with only names?
Than u can do that:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("your xml file");
foreach (var elem in xDoc.Document.Descendants("city"))
{
    names.Add(elem.Attribute("name").Value);
    name_en.Add(elem.Attribute("name_en").Value);
    (...)
}
```

Comment: ок thank you and how to get in one element country and name and region?

Comment: I think u can add more list to control this. Or create an object  city with that attributes and in parsing insesrt in attributes that names

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to do array or select list with all name of tag for example country."
>
> "I want get all value with tag country and I do not know how"

You can try using [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get array of country names :

```
string url = "http://xml.weather.co.ua/1.2/city/?search=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
var countries = doc.Descendants("city")
                   .Elements("country")
                   .Select(o => (string)o)
                   .ToArray();
```